# unwrapping variable in left side of assignment

Tags: ios, swift

I was reading some code and I saw this:

```
self.currentOffset! = self.scrollView.contentOffset
```

these two variables are defined in a ViewController as bellow:

```
@IBOutlet weak var scrollView: UIScrollView!
var currentOffset: CGPoint!
```

so I'm wondering what's the difference between

```
self.currentOffset! = self.scrollView.contentOffset
```

and

```
self.currentOffset = self.scrollView.contentOffset
```

this maybe seem too simple and obvious, but it's first time that I see unwrapping in left side of = in swift.

Comment: Hmm.. I can’t see why anyone would do that. All I can see is a potential crash if `self.currentOffset` is nil.

Comment: It makes no sense to me. That variable is already implicitly unwrapped and shouldn't require force-unwrapping. Also, you need to unwrap only when you are **get**ting the value from it. Not while **set**ting it.

Comment: Agreed. I expect this was just a mistake.